# Did PIE *h3 cause voicing in any other words than the "drink" word?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, indo-european, reconstruction, assimilation

The Proto-Indo-European "third laryngeal", *h<sub>3</sub>, is often assumed to have been a voiced sound based on the fact that some reflexes of the "drink" root *peh<sub>3</sub>- appear to show voicing assimilation of *p* to *b*: e.g. Sanskrit *pibati* < *pi-ph<sub>3</sub>-, Latin *bibit* similarly with further regressive assimilation.

But whenever I've seen this argued, this "drink" verb is the only piece of evidence presented. Are there other words that show assimilatory voicing of a consonant next to *h<sub>3</sub>? It's true that *h<sub>3</sub> seems to have been the least frequent of the laryngeals, but still, you'd think that more than one data point should be adducible for this process.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there's at least one other suggested, but controversial, case of voicing by *h3, involving the "Hoffmann suffix" *-Hon- or *-h3on-. Piotr Gąsiorowski discusses it [here](http://langevo.blogspot.com/2013/06/wild-waters.html). The same suffix may be responsible for the voicing alternation in Latin pairs like *vertex, vertic-* vs. *vertigo*. I don't know how far these ideas are currently accepted, though.

Comment: Byrd (PIEan Syllable 2015:11,22,25) posits a rule of feature assimilation and says specifically "This form (among others) suggests that laryngeal coloring was blocked across a morpheme boundary; cf. Weiss 2009:50." In this view the Hoffmann-suffix does not work as an example, I guess, unless vowels and consonants behaved differently.

Answer (score -1):

One theory is that it was a labialized sound [xʷ] similar to [kʷ]. Weill would you call [kʷ] a voiced sound? I think, no because such compound sounds are usually assigned voicity according the first component.

Comment: Right, but another theory is that it was a voiced labialized fricative like [ʕʷ]. I'm not sure whether to believe this, which is why I'm asking for more evidence that it was (fully) voiced.

Comment: @TKR for what it worth, in my analysis of PIE roots I noticed that many roots reconstructed with h3 in fact related to the roots reconstructed with u̯ in the same place. Like, say, o̯eron/u̯oron (a kind of bird), o̯rta̯/u̯ertmn (wheel), o̯rdhos (heght, uprightness)/u̯ers (top, peak). Some roots have different reconstructions in different sources.